# Why does Flutter Doctor not find an option named "android --licences"

Tags: android, flutter, installation

I am trying to complete the install of Flutter. Within the Flutter help, it has an option called "Flutter doctors android --licences" However, when you run it, Flutter does not recognise it's own option.

Running Windows 10. I installed from the Zip folder. And have installed Android Studio.

When I run c:> flutter doctor android--licences I get an error

> could not find an option named "android --licences"

Both Flutter and Android studio have been added to my path.

I have run `$ flutter config --android-sdk "C:\Users\vince\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"`

I have tried running `sdkmanager --update` from inside the Android sdk folder as well as inside the bin folder to no avail.

I have checked innumerable posts on SO as well as GIT. All without success.

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Its `flutter doctor --android-licenses` not `Flutter doctors android --licences`. mind the spaces

Comment: Thanks for that, I tried both - it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Mate, try --android-licenses NO android --licences (mind your spelling. s not c)

Answer (score 1):

close the terminal you're using and go to your flutter installation folder
find a .bat file named `flutter_console.bat` click it to run it once again and just right the below command

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Hope it will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `flutter doctor -v` which gives more details.
This will enable you to see the particular licences that are not accepted.
You can now run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept them one by one by typing `y` (for yes) each time.